# How do I concatenate these strings in vim?

Tags: vim, concatenation

I have two string variables:

```
let url = "https://URL/path/to/repo"
let branch = "GIT-HASH"
```

I want to concatentate them and echo it on the shell:

```
let result = url . branch
exec '!echo '.result
```

I only ever see `url` in the output, and never `branch`. I can echo `branch` by itself and that works, I can put `branch` before `url` and that works, but `url . branch` does not work. `url .. branch` produces the same result. Why isn't this working?

Vim version is compiled from `v8.2.4236`

Comment: `:execute "!echo " . url . branch` should work just fine, as would `:execute "!echo " . result`.

Comment: Why not just `:echo result` ? PS. Anyway `:exec '!echo '.result` works for me, the output is `https://URL/path/to/repoGIT-HASH`

Comment: Maybe it's interference from your environment? Try `vim --clean`